# Typescript utility type with an Intersection

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

I have two types:

```js
type A = {
  'a-first-key': SomeType
  'a-second-key': SomeOtherType
}

type B = {
  'b-first-key': DifferentType
  'b-second-key': AnotherDifferentType
}
```

I am intersecting these types together for use in a generic function:

```js
type Intersection = A & B

function genericFunction<T extends keyof Intersection>(
  key: T,
  data: Intersection[T]
) {
  // ...
}
```

And the function is used like so:

```js
const result = genericFunction('a-second-key', data)
// typescript will correctly error here if 'data' is not of type 'SomeOtherType' - nice!
```

and all is working well.

#### Problem

I would now like to append some data, `DeviceInfo`, to all of my types:

```js
type DeviceInfo = {
  os: string
  manufacturer: string
}

// and I want to then intersect this with all of my types
type A = {
  'a-first-key': SomeType & DeviceInfo
  'a-second-key': SomeOtherType & DeviceInfo
}

type B = {
  'b-first-key': DifferentType & DeviceInfo
  'b-second-key': AnotherDifferentType & DeviceInfo
}
```

But this looks ugly to me, and I have a long list of intersection types where I would need to do this, and I would much prefer to write a generic type `WithDeviceInfo` that can do this automatically for me:

```js
type Intersection = WithDeviceInfo<A & B>
```

However I cannot seem to get this working. I have tried to do:

```js
type WithDeviceInfo<T> = Record<keyof T, T & DeviceInfo>
```

but this seems to end up wrong and all muddled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use mapped types, not `Record`.
Try something like

```js
type WithDeviceInfo<T> = {
  [K in keyof T]: T[K] & DeviceInfo;
}
```